# including hibernate-validator breaks existing hibernate configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I am writing a java module in which I have used hibernate validator. The module works fine by itself.

However when it is included as part of a parent project which uses hibernate for standard entity mapping as an ORM, the parent module breaks down by complaining that it is unable to set up the validation factory (and thus fails to setup the session factory).

exception message is "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory"

-Pulkit

EDIT:
hibernate-validator : 4.3.1.Final
hibernate-core : 3.6.5

Stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'messageSourceServiceTarget' defined in class
path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'mutableResourceBundleMessageSource' while setting
bean property 'activeMessageSource'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'mutableResourceBundleMessageSource' defined
in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]:
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name
'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0'
defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionInterceptor' while
setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path
resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property
'transactionManager'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
resource [applicationContext-service.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable
to get the default Bean Validation factory
```

Comment: Which versions of ORM and Validator do you use? Also, do you have a complete stacktrace?

Comment: The interesting part of your stack trace is missing and that's the cause for the last HibernateException. That would tell us more on why the default ValidatorFactory could not be build. I assume you have the Bean Validation API on the classpath as well, right? Which version? When you are saying that you are writing a module, what exactly do you mean. Could there be any class loading constraints at play? Btw, this is the relevant code - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/beanvalidation/TypeSafeActivator.java#L383